# Ternary Conversion in Python not working well. Why?

Tags: python, ternary

I've tried to make a ternary calculator on Python, with some other functions like hex, bin, and oct with the built-in functions. There isn't one for ternary so I built one.

```
def ternary(n):
    e = n/3
    q = n%3
    e = n/3
    q = e%3
    return q

i = int(input("May you please give me a number: "))
print("Binary "+bin(i))
print("Octal "+oct(i))
print("Hexadecimal "+hex(i))
print("Ternary "+ternary(i))
enter code here
```

But it doesn't work. Why? Where is the problem?

Comment: You should use `print("Binary " ,bin(i))` instead of `+` because for `+` to work both should be of string or same type.

Comment: Your algorithm for converting to ternary is not even close to correct. You need a loop that repeats the calculations for each digit, and appends them to the result.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code which others have pointed out in the comments, but I'll reiterate them

- You are using regular division when you want to use integer division (in Python 3).
- You are returning an integer from your function whereas `bin`, `oct`, and `hex` all return strings.

In addition, your ternary function is incorrect, even with the errors fixed.  The best way to write a function for base conversion on your own is with recursion.

```
def ternary(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        e = n//3
        q = n%3
        return ternary(e) + str(q)
```